# How to forward Wireguard traffic to shadowsocks by provided urls?

Tags: linux, vpn, docker, proxy, wireguard

I have 2 servers on separate hosts: wireguard and shadowsocks. They work as expected.

Wireguard server config in docker container (*0.0.0.0:51821->51821/tcp, :::51821->51821/tcp, 0.0.0.0:51820->51820/udp, :::51820->51820/udp*):

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.20.30.1/24
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = <private_key>
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o `ip route | awk '/default/ {print $5; exit}'` -j MASQUERADE; ip rule add from `ip addr show $(ip route | awk '/default/ { print $5 }') | grep "inet" | grep -v "inet6" | head -n 1 | awk '/inet/ {print $2}' | awk -F/ '{print $1}'` table main;
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o `ip route | awk '/default/ {print $5; exit}'` -j MASQUERADE; ip rule del from `ip addr show $(ip route | awk '/default/ { print $5 }') | grep "inet" | grep -v "inet6" | head -n 1 | awk '/inet/ {print $2}' | awk -F/ '{print $1}'` table main;
```

Shadowsocks with simple docker compose config:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
    shadowsocks:
        image: shadowsocks/shadowsocks-libev:v3.3.5
        ports:
            - '8388:8388/tcp'
            - '8388:8388/udp'
        environment:
            - METHOD=aes-256-gcm
            - PASSWORD=somepass
        restart: always
```

I need to forward traffic from wg to ss server, but with provided rules - a list of URL addresses o URL masks.

To get the following diagram:

[image]

I have tried various methods such as

- set up native linux iptables, ip routes
- tun2socks lib (forwards all traffic)

But I couldn’t make a successfully working model, especially by wrapping it in Docker.

So I'm asking the community for help.